# Interpolating missing values in multi-line graph ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, interpolation

[image: graph with broken lines]I've used the word interpolating despite not fully knowing its meaning. I have a multi-line graph, and where there are missing values in the dataset the lines on the graph just break (See France in the early 20th century, there's a gap). I'm wondering how to 'fill' the line so that the breaks in data don't show. I've tried to 'smoothen' but wasn't able to download the ggalt package. Now I'm thinking I need to 'interpolate.' Is someone able to help? Many thanks :')

```
 ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=df_France, aes(x=YEAR, y=CENTAXGDP, color="France"), group=1) + #note: putting color=within the bracket makes it group by variable, not change it's color
  geom_line(data=df_Australia, aes(x=YEAR, y=CENTAXGDP, color="Australia"), group=1) +
  geom_line(data=df_Norway, aes(x=YEAR, y=CENTAXGDP, color="Norway"), group=1) +
  geom_line(data=df_Sweden, aes(x=YEAR, y=CENTAXGDP, color="Sweden"), group=1) +
  geom_line(data=df_USA, aes(x=YEAR, y=CENTAXGDP, color="USA"), group=1) + 
  geom_line(data=df_Denmark, aes(x=YEAR, y=CENTAXGDP, color="Denmark", group=1)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,40),
                     labels=scales::label_percent(scale=1),
                     expand = expansion(0,0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks=35) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("France" = "red", "Australia" = "blue", "Norway" = "green", "Sweden" = "purple", "USA" = "black", "Denmark" = "pink")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, vjust=1, hjust=1)) +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("% of GDP") +
  labs(color="Country") +
  ggtitle("Total central government tax revenue as a share of GDP: 1800-2012") +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

Someone helped me greatly on StackOverflow once with a similar problem, so I tried to replicate what they did:

```
df %>%
  mutate(is_real = !is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(color) %>%
   mutate(value = pracma::interp1(df$YEAR, value, df$YEAR, "linear"))
```

Error message comes up:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `is_real`.
ℹ `is_real = !is.na(value)`.
x object 'value' not found
```

Comment: On the mere technical level, you need to use your actual column names, e.g. `mutate(CENTAXGDP = pracma::interp1(YEAR, CENTAXGDP, YEAR, "linear"))`. However, make sure to not mislead your audience (and yourself) into mistaking the guessed (interpolated) values for real observations. For follow-ups, please provide a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).